# How do I connect my application to eXist-DB

Tags: c#, database, exist-db

i've created a c# application that is effectively a workflow system that moves XML documents around folder structures depending on their status, among other things.

What i'd now like to do is use a database to store the XML files instead of local folders, but I still need to be able to query them with Linq / XQuery. I've chosen eXist-DB as my database it is gets some fairly good praise.

My question is, how do I connect to my newly created DB from my C# application. If i choose the 'Connect to a DB' option in Visual Studio i'm presnted with a bunch of SQL server options, but nothing that appears to be of any use to connect to my nice new eXist DB.